# Capture video on ios using PJSIP

Tags: ios, video, pjsip

i am not able to render or capture video on ios.
After successful SDP negtiation i tried to add video call for existing audio call, in on_call_media_state callback i observed that the media is not active for video.
When i hung up the call i get the following log which shows `#1 video H263-1998, inactive, peer=10.11.201.147:50858.`
According to Siphon some are able to get the video stream on ios devices.

Any help would be appreciated

```
3-11-15 14:59:39.075 ipjsua[220:6007] 14:59:39.075    pjsua_app.c  .....Call 1 is DISCONNECTED [reason=200 (Normal call clearing)]
2013-11-15 14:59:39.093 ipjsua[220:6007] 14:59:39.093    pjsua_app.c  .....
2013-11-15 14:59:39.097 ipjsua[220:6007]   [DISCONNCTD] To: "102" <sip:102@10.11.201.147>;tag=bf76b652

    Call time: 00h:04m:04s, 1st res in 121 ms, conn in 674ms
#0 audio speex @16kHz, sendrecv, peer=10.11.201.147:22268
    SRTP status: Not active Crypto-suite: (null)
    RX pt=100, last update:00h:00m:00.627s ago
    total 12.1Kpkt 1.29MB (1.78MB +IP hdr) @avg=42.2Kbps/58.2Kbps
    pkt loss=4 (0.0%), discrd=0 (0.0%), dup=0 (0.0%), reord=0 (0.0%)
    (msec)    min     avg     max     last    dev
    loss period:  20.000  20.000  20.000  20.000   0.000
    jitter     :   0.000   6.258  32.187  14.500   3.978
    TX pt=100, ptime=20, last update:00h:00m:02.013s ago
    total 8.3Kpkt 249.0KB (581.7KB +IP hdr) @avg=8.1Kbps/19.0Kbps
    pkt loss=152 (1.8%), dup=0 (0.0%), reorder=0 (0.0%)
    (msec)    min     avg     max     last    dev
    loss period:  20.000  49.836 140.000 120.000  25.816
    jitter     :   5.500  20.248  75.750  33.250  14.885
    RTT msec      :   5.966  50.438 146.325 131.000  33.555
#1 video H263-1998, inactive, peer=10.11.201.147:50858
    SRTP status: Not active Crypto-suite: (null)
    RX  last update:00h:01m:30.404s ago
    total 12pkt 48B (528B +IP hdr) @avg=2bps/22bps
    pkt loss=0 (0.0%), discrd=0 (0.0%), dup=0 (0.0%), reord=0 (0.0%)
    (msec)    min     avg     max     last    dev
    loss period:   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
    jitter     :  -0.001   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
    TX  last update:00h:01m:03.332s ago
    total 0pkt 0B (0B +IP hdr) @avg=0bps/0bps
    pkt loss=1 (100.0%), dup=0 (0.0%), reorder=0 (0.0%)
    (msec)    min     avg     max     last    dev
    loss period:   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
    jitter     :   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
    RTT msec      :   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
#2 video H263-1998, inactive, peer=10.11.201.147:22264
    SRTP status: Not active Crypto-suite: (null)
    RX  last update:00h:01m:39.059s ago
    total 15pkt 60B (660B +IP hdr) @avg=2bps/27bps
    pkt loss=0 (0.0%), discrd=2 (13.3%), dup=2 (13.3%), reord=0 (0.0%)
    (msec)    min     avg     max     last    dev
    loss period:   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
    jitter     :  -0.001   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
    TX  last update:00h:01m:08.467s ago
    total 0pkt 0B (0B +IP hdr) @avg=0bps/0bps
    pkt loss=1 (100.0%), dup=0 (0.0%), reorder=0 (0.0%)
    (msec)    min     avg     max     last    dev
    loss period:   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
    jitter     :   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
    RTT msec      :   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2013-11-15 14:59:39.214 ipjsua[220:6007] 14:59:39.214  pjsua_media.c  .....Call 1: deinitializing media..
2013-11-15 14:59:39.231 ipjsua[220:6007] 14:59:39.231  pjsua_media.c  .......Media stream call01:0 is destroyed
2013-11-15 14:59:39.253 ipjsua[220:6007] 14:59:39.253    pjsua_vid.c  .......Stopping video stream..
2013-11-15 14:59:39.259 ipjsua[220:6007] 14:59:39.259  pjsua_media.c  .......Media stream call01:1 is destroyed
2013-11-15 14:59:39.264 ipjsua[220:6007] 14:59:39.264    pjsua_vid.c  .......Stopping video stream..
2013-11-15 14:59:39.276 ipjsua[220:6007] 14:59:39.276  pjsua_media.c  .......Media stream call01:2 is destroyed
2013-11-15 14:59:40.232 ipjsua[220:6007] 14:59:40.231    pjsua_aud.c  Closing sound device after idle for 1 second(s)
2013-11-15 14:59:40.234 ipjsua[220:6007] 14:59:40.234    pjsua_app.c  .Turning sound device OFF
2013-11-15 14:59:40.253 ipjsua[220:6007] 14:59:40.252    pjsua_aud.c  .Closing iPhone IO device sound playback device and iPhone IO device sound capture device
2013-11-15 14:59:40.415 ipjsua[220:6007] 14:59:40.415 coreaudio_dev.  .core audio stream stopped
2013-11-15 15:00:33.609 ipjsua[220:6007] 15:00:33.608   pjsua_core.c  .RX 719 bytes Request msg SUBSCRIBE/cseq=52 (rdata0xa41a14) from UDP 10.11.201.147:5060:
SUBSCRIBE sip:101@10.11.208.114:5060;ob SIP/2.0



2013-11-15 15:19:54.347 ipjsua[220:6007] 15:19:54.347    pjsua_app.c  .....Call 2 is DISCONNECTED [reason=200 (Normal call clearing)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PJSIP on iOS does not currently implement Video Media.

The data sheet states which OSs video is implemented for:

Video Media

- Platforms:

  - Windows,
  - Linux,
  - Mac
- Codecs:

  - H.263-1998 (ffmpeg),
  - H.264 (ffmpeg and x264)
- Capture devices:

  - colorbar (all platforms)
  - DirectShow (Windows)
  - Video4Linux2 (Linux)
  - QuickTime (Mac OS X)
- Rendering devices:

  - SDL (Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X)
  - DirectShow (Windows)

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/PJSIP-Datasheet

Further, the video user guide states that mobile OSs are not yet supported:

> Video is available on PJSIP version 2.0 and later. Only desktop platforms are supported, mobile devices such as iOS are not yet supported.

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Video_Users_Guide